# How to display data with Firebase and Android Studio using a spinner

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to show all the registered business in my FirebaseDB from a specific city, when the user registered in the same city.

[My DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VnB0v.png)

The "Cliente" and the "Socio" have registered their cities with a spinner, but I can´t show each business "Barberias" from city "Mexicali, when the user is form the same city.
Help!!

[This is my code!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xDkRt.png)

Here is my code to show specific data from the city of "Mexicali", that´s what I want to know, if a user live in Miami, I want to show him all the "Barberias" from Miami :D

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you elaborate on what you have tried, what happens and why this is not the desired result? You can edit your question. This enables us to better help you with your questions.

Comment: Buddy! I edited my comment :D